# Kinetic energy with respect to center of mass frame (COM)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, kinematics, mass

Let there be an object having some chemicals in it. It starts moving with a uniform velocity $v$ and a chemical reaction starts happening. In this case, which of the following statement/s is/are correct?

1. Chemical reactions happening. The system cannot change the velocity $v$ of the center of mass.
2. Chemical reactions happening in the system cannot change the kinetic energy of the particles inside with respect to the center of mass.

I know the first is correct because internal forces cannot change $v_{COM}$. But what about the second? I think that second should be false as chemical energy may change into kinetic energy and hence KE can increase.

Also, Is the expression for KE with respect to COM equal to total KE minus the KE of COM?
If yes then 2 is false can also be seen from here as KE of COM is fixed but total KE can change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) is correct because momentum is conserved when a system is not subjected to  a net external force (isolated system).

(2) is not correct because kinetic energy of an isolated system is not necessarily conserved. Only total energy (kinetic plus potential) is conserved. In this case, kinetic plus chemical potential energy.

Consider the reaction to be an explosion. The sum of the kinetic energies of the exploded particles is greater than the kinetic energy of the object before the explosion, the difference equal to the loss of chemical potential energy plus other forms of energy (internal microscopic kinetic energy due to heat, kinetic energy of sound, etc.). The kinetic energy of the center of mass of the exploded particles, however, does not change because of (1).

Hope this helps.